# How to override a field in the parent class

Tags: python, django, class, overriding

I have parent and child classes in Django model. And I want to fill a field in parent class when initialize child class. Or override this field in child class.

```
    class Parent(models.Model):
        type = models.CharField()

    class Child(Parent):
        type = models.CharField()  //Doesn't work
```

Also trying override init method, but it doesn't work too. 
How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> In normal Python class inheritance, it is permissible for a child class to override any attribute from the parent class. In Django, this is not permitted for attributes that are Field instances (at least, not at the moment). If a base class has a field called author, you cannot create another model field called author in any class that inherits from that base class.

You can't. [Reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#field-name-hiding-is-not-permitted)