# Updated inherited django model field attributes?

Tags: python, django, django-models

Say I'm inheriting from the django user class:

```
# import AbstractUser class ....
class MyUser(AbstractUser):

    gender = models.Charfield(....
    ....
    # I want to make the email field blank=False and unique=True
    # however, to my knowledge, python doesn't allow you to 
    # override inherited fields
```

So How do I make the email field blank=False and unique=True.  Note: I'm also using South, so South friendly code would be nice. (Note: I'm using Django 1.5, so hoping for a solution so I won't have to create my own User Model from AbstractBaseUser)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class MyUser(AbstractUser):

    gender = models.Charfield(....

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
       super(self, MyUser).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
       email = models.EmailField(blank=False, unique=True)
       email.contribute_to_class('email', self)
```

Comment: tried to override email, don't think it worked because South indicated that their were duplicated fields.  Also see http://stackoverflow.com/a/6899713/749477.

Comment: I forgot you can override it by using AbstractBaseUser not AbstractUser

Comment: email is defined as a field in AbstractUser, which is the class I want to use rather than AbstractBaseUser. So while your answer works, it's not overriding the field, which is what I prefer.

Comment: Ok got it, hmmmmm... I will try another

Comment: nah, it's okay, I've switched to just using AbstractBaseUser.  Check mark for the effort and time. But if you could find a solution, that would be amazing.

Comment: Yeah thank you and I will because I will be using CBV's for my next big project. I will be studying on how to do it :)